# No display but video card fans spins

Tags: graphics-card, display

Since I moved my computer
there's no display when I plug my screen in the video card
but works fine in the mother board.
I tried reseting the cmos, but I still have the same problem.

The fans are spining and there's a light from the card. I tried the DVI ports and the HDMI

Here's my build. I have it for 2 months and everything was working fine.
Do you think it's the video card?

- Asus p8z68-v pro gen3
- Intel i7 2600k
- 120 GB OCZ Agility 3
- 16 GB RAM Blue Corsair DDR3
- Asus GTX 570
- H80 Corsair liquid cooling
- XFX PRO750W 80Plus bronze power supply

EDIT
That's why
[image]

And I can't push more cause the card is on this
[image]

Thank you everyone! I fixed it by pushing the mobo from the other side of the case and now it fits.

Comment: Can you clarify - does it work with the *onboard* video?  If so there's probably just a BIOS setting to make the offboard the primary.

Comment: sorry, yes it works fine on the onboard video. Can you help me with the bios setting, I can't see anything about that

Comment: Not familiar with this motherboard, sorry, but in my experience newer ASUS boards don't have a very complicated BIOS.  It's probably in the onboard device settings if it's not in its own category.  Another possibility - the auxillary power for that GTX 570 might not be attached or might not be working.

Comment: But the fans are working and the light on the card is on :( could it still be power problem?

Comment: Yes, I've seen that happen before.  Just because the fan is going doesn't mean anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you mean when the system starts you do not get video. If this is the case, then you need to turn the computer off, re-install the graphics card, and properly secure it because it likely came loose when moving. If you properly secure a graphics card it should never come lose during travel, so make sure to actually screw it in. If this does not resolve it then either you are not properly powering it now (PSU failure maybe) or your graphics card has failed.

If you mean it shows something when the computer turns on, then turns off when it loads Windows, then that means Windows is disabling the output. When you boot into Windows (or whatever your OS is), you will need to enable the monitors on that graphics card. To do this you will need to plug one into your motherboard connected ports, boot into Windows, then enable the displays, make at least one the primary, and that will at least get one working. Then when you have one of your monitors on the graphics card, you can swap the other one onto the graphics card and enable it.

Comment: My \*local currency fractions\* are on the PSU.

Comment: The system starts, but the screen has no signal. Can it be a power problem even if the fans are working and the light on the card is on?

Comment: @bloodylron The system starts, but the screen has no signal. Can it be a power problem even if the fans are working and the light on the card is on?

Comment: You mentioned that your motherboard has display connectors, if this is correct do this. Turn system off. Plug monitor into a port on the motherboard. If it turns on, but you do not get video, try ALL the ports, both on the motherboard and on the graphics card, even if they are different video connection ports (HDMI instead of DVI), try them all. If you get NO video from ALL of them after following this explicit order, your graphics card may have failed, or something else is causing your POST (Power On Self Test) to fail.

Comment: If, as outlined in my last post, your POST is failing (no video on all ports in this case), try taking out all the RAM except one stick. Then turning it on. Same result? No video? Turn off, try another stick. Do this until you've tried all sticks of RAM by itself. If you are doing this on a system EARLIER than Intel Core i series processors (i3/i5/i7) make sure each RAM stick is closest to the CPU. If you are using an i series processor, make sure it is in the SECOND TO nearest slot to the processor. As in, if counting away from the CPU, in slot 2.

Comment: All the ports on my motherboard work, but none on my video card. The post is not failing even with graphic card

Comment: This is really peculiar. I would say try updating your BIOS? If this does not resolve it, try resetting your BIOS to default settings after the update is performed. If you STILL cannot get video, contact the manufacturer.

Comment: thank you but I updated the bios 2 weeks ago to the last one, and I reset the bios with the jumper. I will try with another PCI port on the board.

Comment: @BloodyIron I think I found my problem. The card is not totally in the pci slot. The case is too large so half of the pci is fully in :( Hard to explain, I will take a picture.  It works now, but im scared that it could break my card if it moves while it's on

Comment: @marc if you can't properly eecure your graphics card due to space constraints (can't screw it in?) don't use it till you get a proper case that can handle it. You're going to regret it if you kill one of your PCIe connectors, or the card itself.

Comment: What @BloodyIron said - you're just going to damage components if it doesn't properly fit.  If you just didn't have it installed properly because you were afraid to put force on it, well, that explains your problem and is a solution in and of itself.

Comment: I'm gonna find a way to take a picture and upload it here. I have no idea of what to do with this

Comment: @Shinrai I uploaded the pictures. is that normal?

Comment: @BloodyIron I uploaded the pictures. is that normal?

Comment: @Marc it's definitely not seating fully, but I can't make heads or tails of your second picture.  Is it catching on the back plate?  Try removing the surrounding slot plates and make sure it's not getting caught on one - also make sure the BOTTOM end isn't getting stuck down at the bottom of the slot.  Don't be afraid to push a little bit.

Comment: wow that's a quick reply thank you. No it's not on the black plate. It's screw on the frame of the case. I could try to screw it under the frame instead on top. But I thought it was supposed to be a standard and everything should fit...

Comment: @Marc yeah if you look at it, the front of the card (towards the case) is not in properly. You shouldn't be able to see so much gold connector.

Comment: Thank you everyone! I fixed it by pushing the mobo from the other side of the case and now it fits.